# Google Sheets: How to have conditional formatting based on each individual cell?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet where it's a table full of people's Euro Cup soccer picks. I want to have a column at the end where I type the winning team into a cell. If that value matches then I want the cell to turn green, or else turn red, else if empty stay white.

I can do conditional formatting for every single cell but this would take forever since there's hundreds. If I select the range, can I do a formula where I specify that cell? Like how if I type row() it gives me that row, can I do something like -

```
if cell() === row() column 50
then green
else if cell() === ""
white
else 
red
```

I need some help with the syntax too if this is possible

*Edit - Here is an example of my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KcUnRg2UuqfnjX7TehAAluNEcDDbs2utErh1eLPczNM/edit?usp=sharing

I want conditional formatting so that the cells in A to E change color depending on the text in Cell F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a Google Sheet to fiddle around with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ca7o1mVTsu8m3ONcTxTYeNRTnxUJZaeXe4Kuy-6kxGI/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to change it as you please in case I didn't understand your case correctly.

Comment: Do you know a way to get the cells in column D to change color depending on the text in column F? So D3 would be green, D4 red

Comment: I have just copied the conditional formatting rules from F3:F5 to D3:D5. So now both entries are colored in case the pick equals the winner. Is this now working like you wanted it?